# mysql order by timestamp latest and group the rows of that category with limit

Tags: mysql, sql, greatest-n-per-group

Order by timestamp DESC and group by a category with a limit in Mysql

```
cat  timestamp
----------------
11   1308748405
11   1308747228
13   1308749273
57   1308748289
11   1308746228
```

...to get a table of the format, where it is sorted by timestamp and also relevant rows of that category grouped together with a limit. (ie group by category of all rows and arrange amoung the groups by the descending order of timestamps but keep the group together)

```
cat  timestamp
----------------
13   1308749273
11   1308748405
11   1308747228
57   1308748389
```

Comment: group by category? Your result example has the same category twice (11). Is that on purpose?

Comment: yes ie first order by timestamp and for each timestamp, do a subquery of all the related or similar items based on the category... this usually leads to the latest items shown with the related items grouped together

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing what you are looking for is: Get the minimum timestamp per category, and sort the results by timestamp?

```
SELECT t.cat, t.timestamp
FROM table t
JOIN (SELECT MIN(timestamp) as min_time, cat
        FROM table
        GROUP BY cat) as tmp
      ON (t.cat = tmp.cat AND t.timestamp = tmp.min_time)
ORDER BY 2 DESC
```

Comment: this query results in 13 1308749273 57 1308748289 11 1308746228

Comment: group by category  of all rows and arrange amoung the groups by the descending order of timestamps but keep the group together

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT cat, timestamp
FROM yourtable
ORDER BY timestamp DESC
GROUP BY cat
LIMIT 4
```

without more details, this is the best you're going to get.

Comment: in mysql can we do order by group by ...I thought it was group by order by ...but then the group by shows only one row per category

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get 4 groups based on sorted by it's latest timestamp. This may works:

```
SELECT tblTes.cat, tblTes.timestamp 
FROM tblTes INNER JOIN (SELECT cat, MAX(TIMESTAMP) AS latest FROM tblTes GROUP BY cat) AS subQuery 
ON tblTes.cat = subQuery.cat AND tblTes.timestamp = subQuery.latest 
ORDER BY tblTes.timestamp DESC LIMIT 4;
```

Comment: this also groups it 1 per cat 13 1308749273
   11 1308748405
   57 1308748289

Comment: What if you don't know the numbers of groups? Can you limit something to 1?